# Is there a way to prioritize MSAccess form validation rules rather than SQL's in a linked table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I'm creating a program in which I want to catch errors in data formatting on the front end within MS Access however, when I try to create rules within MS Access I get the error Table ' ' is a linked table whose design can't be modified. If you want to add or remove fields or change their properties or data types, you must do so in the source database. This is a problem because I think that MS Access' rules are generally better and catch errors on the front end. Is there a way I can use the MS Access rules but still have it be a linked table to the SQL server and flow data that way?

Comment: If you want to ensure the formatting of the values in SQL Server, then either ensure you are using the right data type (such as a `date` for dates) or use `CHECK` `CONSTRAINT`s.

Comment: Create rules in the form, not in table design. For more advanced rules, use Form_BeforeUpdate event.

Comment: @Andre This looks like it may work. However, I'm working with a set of data types that range between dates (yyyy-mm-dd format), numerics, and varchars. I'm looking at it from the form view right now in properties and I don't see a way to change the data type to fit these conditions. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I was refering to [Validation rules](http://allenbrowne.com/ValidationRule.html) for controls. But using the `Format` property you can at least enforce Numeric or Date input.

Comment: @Andre Oh I see now! Thank you so much man! Huge help! I'll try this out and see if it works.

Comment: @Andre All of that worked. Thank you so much for your help. I was hoping you could help me with one last problem as well. I'm having a difficult time doing military time or short time in the form view. I have someone running into an error where they put in 15:83 which shouldn't be allowed because the minutes are over 59, as well hours being over 23. However, I'm not sure how to create a form validation for something like that and I can't seem to find any documentation for it online.

Answer (score 0):

If you check validation rule properties of the control, then go to expression builder, functions, built in functions, you will see inspection(this is category of functions)

e.g =IsNumeric([searchtext]) ensures only numbers can be entered in the searchtext control.

Look at the image i attached for other inspection functions.

[image]